# ripple effect resumes after fragment back stack pop

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using native Fragments and a fragment transaction with `add()` and `hide()`. When I go back to the original fragment with the back button, the ripple animation from `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` resumes from when I opened the fragment originally. How do I cancel an animation when hiding a fragment in a transaction?

```java
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .hide(this)
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit()
```

**Edit:**
I am changing my app to use ViewPager.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your approach of handling fragments, i would suggest you use `fragementTransaction.replace()` instead of Adding fragment and it would be better if you could post your code where you handling fragments

Comment: Well maybe I have to backtrack a bit. The reason I am using `hide()` instead of `replace()` is that I don't want my `RecyclerView` to have to reload when I go back to it.

Comment: Hmmm you have to find another way then if you want it to be like so, because adding a fragment creates more complexity, I use fragments a lot  in my apps and I have found `replace()` best choice so far